# Push notifications for desktop apps

Tags: c#, json, desktop-application, pubnub

Push notifications for mobile apps allow for some cool possibilities in terms of user experience. Are similar services available for desktop apps, such as those written in C#?

My goal is to push notifications when a value is inserted into the database and to display that on others users screen so everybody it will be updated.

If I do this from database it will take too long to refresh always the database and display information.

I was thinking to send this notifications as JSON.

I read about PubNub but I couldn`t find any example for desktop apps, just mobile.

Comment: The PubNub team is working on a C# example for triggering desktop notifications, simultaneously, for all clients subscribed to a channel. I will post a guide here soon.

Comment: Perfect! Looking forward for that guide.

Comment: Hey I was able to complete the guide. https://www.pubnub.com/blog/c-sharp-desktop-notifications-wpf-mvvm/?devrel_so=push-notifications-for-desktop-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [PushBullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) can be of help, just know you will then introduce a third-party. PushBullet has a very easy to use API and Nuget-packages.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing with UWP framework, there is no difference between mobile and desktop modes. Push notifications would appear like any other Win10 notification, at the Action Center expandable area.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!